# debugging a c++ dll in VS2010, from python

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll

I have a dll built in c++, under VS2010, and I am calling it from a python project.

I had an error, inside the dll, and I would have liked to be able to debug using VS tools, step into the solution until I reach the task that "read an invalid memory location".

The debug / stepping into functions didn't step into the function code inside the dll.

I tried to attach the debugger (and run the python code from command line/ stop at a raw_input that gave me the pid, then attach the debugger). Same thing happened. I hit the breakpoints inside the python code, but none inside the dll.

I eventually found my error, after much banging my head against my monitor, using old-style trace inside the dll. But there has to be a way to be able to debug an existing/ open project inside VS... I am going to run into this again, so I hope to learn something now, and avoid damage to my monitor in the future. :)

Note: the c++ dll and the pdb file are located both in the same directory as the python file, they are of course automatically built into the Debug folder, and they are also in a folder located into the system path. Any possible DEBUG symbols are enabled. I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the .pdb file in your bin directory if you want to be able to step into and debug a dll, otherwise you will not have access to any of the debugging symbols.  This .pdb allows visual studio to read the .dll file and step into its method calls.

Comment: Where is the bin directory ? I had to manually specify the path to my dll for cdll.LoadLibrary - in path\foldername\output\Win32\Debug\. That is where I see the .pdb file as well. I have no bin directory - the python solution doesn't create any additional directories.

Comment: Ok if the pdb file is already there then it should load those symbols when you build the project.  The when you run the exe you can attach the debugger to this process and it should step into the file when you hit that part of the code(put a breakpoint on the first method to use the dll)

Comment: It didn't though - and that is why I am so confused. BTW, I called the dll from a python program (not an exe)

Comment: Have you tried launching the program externally and then attaching the debugger to the process? For dll's that is usually what you have to do to get them picked up.

Comment: yes I tried - see paragraph 3 from my post. That is how someone else (not from a forum) suggested. It didn't work.